# Do apps which access the network count towards my ISP's bandwidth?

Tags: virtual-machine, networking, bandwidth, isp

When an application uses the internet or even a remote network location, does this count towards the bandwidth quota of my ISP? What if the machine is virtual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, any WAN traffic counts toward your bandwidth quota.  Any Local Area Network traffic doesn't, however.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it does. Any **outbound or inbound** network traffic is measured and metered. Your ISP doesn't care about what the traffic is, only that there's traffic - and they tend to count upload and download towards your cap, too. Local traffic, however - traffic that neither comes from the internet, nor ever touches it, your ISP not only does not count, but cannot see.

Comment: This response is confusing to me. Any traffic that is sent over the LAN shouldn't count towards the cap, but any traffic that goes out the internet should count.

Comment: @Nathan Adams: edited to make it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 4):

If it goes across the link between your LAN and your ISP then it probably counts as part of your quota. Ask your ISP for further details.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if the app accesses a computer inside your internal network (such as another computer on your local router) then no it doesn't count towards your bandwidth.
If your only connection to the internet is through your ISP and the application accesses the ineternet then yes it does count (assuming your ISP counts all types of traffic).