# What's the bandwidth between two VMs on the same host

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, bandwidth

I have two Virtualbox VMs, the network configuration of one is NAT and the other one is NAT+host-only adapter.My host is a desktop located in a university lab with Local Area Connection 100.0 Mbps, Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller #2.

Could anyone please tell me when I transfer files between these two VMs, does the traffic go through LAN or not?

The Linux command iperf gave me around 180-300Mbps bandwidth between these two VMs in a 10-second interval. Does this mean the maximum available bandwidth between two VMs are about this much?

Thanks very much!

Comment: The answer to [Do apps which access the network count towards my ISP's bandwidth?](http://superuser.com/questions/136569/do-apps-which-access-the-network-count-towards-my-isps-bandwidth?rq=1) is relevant

Answer (score 2):

The VMs' network access is managed on the host through bridging or NATing.  It's therefore the host that will direct the traffic to the right place which obviously doesn't need to leave the actual computer (and doesn't).

The speed obtained for such transfer will depend on the virtual network adapters used on both machines unless the host's load is so high that it could impact its operations.

Comment: Hello Julie, thanks for your reply. So if my desktop's LAN speed is 100.0Mbps, the speed between two VMs should be higher than that. At the time of my iperf test, both VMs are only running the basic programs and daemons, so the value I got (180-300) should be the speed range between these two. Is that correct?

Comment: Considering that you got speeds that are not conventional adapter speeds, it probably implies that the host is not able to let them perform at their highest rate.  As you can notice, it is not limited to the host's adapter speed at all.

Comment: I would watch CPU and swap usage during the transfer since there's obviously a bottleneck occurring.

Comment: Also the NIC drivers on the VMs

Answer (score 0):

You can easily test it by sending a large file from one VM to the other (and make sure you use the right IP's).  Most of the ftp traffic will be UDP.  UDP overhead is about 6% (if you count both the headers and the acks coming back).  If your ftp transfer goes faster than 100Mbps/1.06, then the VM's are communicating faster than the physical device can possibly do.  You want to be careful that the file is large enough to make IP buffers irrelevant (so over 50 MBs), but that the disk IO does not start factoring into the transfer speed because you saturated the memory disk cache on the writing VM (so probably no more than 2GBs).

**Edit:** 
Also, whatever testing method you are using, try running a few of them at the same time in parallel.  Once you reach the point where adding more instances of the test does not increase the network usage anymore, you can consider that to be the peak throughput.  But this will likely be limited by the number of cores dedicated to each VM.  So if you only have 2 cores dedicated to each VM, you won't get any difference in speed between 2 tests and 3 tests running together (even though you might get a higher bandwidth usage from 2 tests than you would from 1).